# How to import Cad models into Blender the easy way

Tags: modeling, import

I use a lot of Cad models I find or make, and I import it into blender to animate. I have always used .STL and then when in Blender I select every triangle and vertex so I can add materials and textures to certain parts. I am wondering If there is someway to import Cad models into Blender and all the parts are already separated so I don't have to select every vertex? This would save me tons of time. Thanks

Comment: Use any format other than STL that supports separate objects. I mean, why STL? That is a digital fabrication oriented format

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose by Loose Parts. That creates a separate object for each group of connected vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Autocad Addon

File user Preferences -> Addon and search for dxf
Activate addon
[image]

Importing the autocad file

File-> import-> Autocad

[image]